# Dynamic Pivot table query with condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table with the details as shown below in the example.

**Example**:

**Table:** test

```
create table test
(
 cola varchar(10),
 colb varchar(10),
 colc varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into test values('111','222','A1');
insert into test values('111','333','A2');
insert into test values('111','344','A3');
insert into test values('111','444','A4');
insert into test values('767','222','A1');
insert into test values('767','333','A2');
insert into test values('767','344','A3');
insert into test values('5443','555','B1');
insert into tft values('8998','222','A1');
insert into tft values('8998','333','A2');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show only that records in which `cola` belongs to `colc`'s values `A1,A2,A3`.

**Expected Result**:

```
cola   A1  A2  A3
------------------
111    1   1   1
767    1   1   1
```

## Attempt:

**Pivot Query**:

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
            from
            (
                select cola,colc
                from test 
            )p
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(colc)
                FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
            )AS pvt'

PRINT(@Sql)
EXEC(@Sql)
```

**Getting Result**:

```
cola    A1  A2  A3
-------------------
111     1   1   1
5443    0   0   0
767     1   1   1
8998    1   1   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to getting the result will be to first return the `cola` values that have `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` in `colc`.  Using `IN` is basically saying `A1` or `A2` or `A3` so you will return rows that have one of these, not all of them.

In order you get the `cola` rows that have all of them, you will need to use a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause to go along with your `WHERE` clause filter.  The basic query would be:

```
select cola
from test
where colc in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
group by cola
having count(distinct colc) = 3;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a64c/6).  Breaking the query down, you'll see there is a `WHERE` clause to filter your `colc` values.  You will use `GROUP BY` on `cola` along with a `HAVING` clause.  The `HAVING` is used to the get the distinct number of `colc` values. In this case, the `HAVING` clause will be checking for rows that have a total of 3 `colc` values when filtered.

Once you have this list, then you can get the final result.  Instead of using `PIVOT` you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

```
select 
  t.cola, 
  sum(case when t.colc = 'A1' then 1 else 0 end) A1,
  sum(case when t.colc = 'A2' then 1 else 0 end) A2,
  sum(case when t.colc = 'A3' then 1 else 0 end) A3
from test t
inner join
(
  select cola
  from test
  where colc in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
  group by cola
  having count(distinct colc) = 3
) d
  on t.cola = d.cola
group by t.cola;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a64c/7)

Typically you'd use dynamic SQL for data that you have unknown values on but if you want to use it for this, you can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = 'A1, A2, A3'

set @query = N'SELECT cola, ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
              select t.cola, t.colc
              from test t
              inner join
              (
                select cola
                from test
                where colc in (''A1'', ''A2'', ''A3'')
                group by cola
                having count(distinct colc) = 3
              ) d
                on t.cola = d.cola
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(colc)
                for colc in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a64c/10)

Comment: There is still wrong result in the above dynamic query. Because If you pass @Stuff = `A1,A2,A3` then it has to show only record `767` but not `111`. Because of record `767` exactly belongs to the `A1,A2,A3` but the `111` belongs to `A1,A2,A3` and `A4` also so it should be appear in the result.

Comment: @MAK You can't change the question after it's already been  answered. If you have new requirements, then you should post a new question with **those requirements**.  I've rolled back your edits that altered the question.

Comment: Okay fine. I will do it now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to filter source data also:

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'
DECLARE @StuffForFilter varchar(max) = '''A1'',''A2'',''A3'''
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
            from
            (
                select cola,colc
                from test
                where colc IN ('+@StuffForFilter+')
            )p
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(colc)
                FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
            )AS pvt'

PRINT(@Sql)
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Getting error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'A3'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'A2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'A1'`.

Comment: @MAK please see my edit; my bad i did not test my code before posting

Comment: Almost done, But still have to satisfies the last record that is `8998` in my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To filter the `Cola` values that have `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` in `colc` use `conditional aggregate`.

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'
DECLARE @StuffForFilter varchar(max) = '''A1'',''A2'',''A3'''
DECLARE @Sql Nvarchar(max)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
            from
            (
                select  t.cola,t.colc
                from #test t join (SELECT cola from (SELECT Max(CASE WHEN colc = ''A1'' THEN 1 END) [a1],
               Max(CASE WHEN colc = ''A2'' THEN 2 END) [a2],
               Max(CASE WHEN colc = ''A3'' THEN 3 END) [a3] ,
               cola
        FROM   #test
        WHERE  colc IN( '+@StuffForFilter+' )
        GROUP  BY cola) A
WHERE  [a1] IS NOT NULL
       AND [a2] IS NOT NULL
       AND [a3] IS NOT NULL ) B on t.cola=B.cola 
            )p
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(colc)
                FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
            )AS pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
+-----+----+---+----+  
|cola | A1 | A2| A3 |
+-----+----+---+----+
|111  | 1  | 1 | 1  |
|767  | 1  | 1 | 1  |
+-----+----+---+----+
```